# Why are the soft sides of trucks sucked inwards at speed?

Tags: aerodynamics

One would have expected there to be lower pressure on the outside of the truck because of the faster airflow  - implying the sidewalls would be sucked outwards.  Of course, there is some flapping and instability as well.  It does not seem to be dependent on the shape of the front of the truck.

Answer (score 0):

They are not pressed inwards over the whole length. At the forward end, they bulge out.

This is caused by flow separation at the forward edges of the truck. The airflow cannot negotiate the sharp corners and separates, producing eddies in which the air pressure drops below its ambient value due to the high local flow speed. Remember that the total pressure is the sum of static and dynamic pressure – high eddy speed means lower local static pressure. This can be seen in measurements made on truck models in [this study](http://www.ifh.uni-karlsruhe.de/science/aerodyn/bilder_orginale/papers/paper%20Ilic.pdf):

[image]

X is the lengthwise direction along the truck body and y the lateral distance. c$_p$ is the pressure coefficient which is zero for ambient pressure and becomes negative with lower pressure. Note the positive pressure in the stagnation area ahead of the truck and the sharp change into suction at the forward section. The pressure along the truck body stays negative along the full length.

Now you need to know that the position of the soft side will not show the absolute pressure but only the pressure difference between inside and outside. Also, it is not completely airtight but leaky. The sharp suction peak at the front will, therefore, lower the pressure in the whole inner space of the truck while it fluctuates between high and almost no suction along the outside of the body.

You are right that suction is prevalent over the whole length of the truck, relative to ambient pressure. But inside there is not that same ambient pressure but some average which is dominated by the sharp suction peak at the forward end. This results in suction along the rear side where the soft skin is sucked inwards.